# nvd3.js chart won't plot in firefox but it works well in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, d3.js, nvd3.js

I've got a d3.js chart that works well in Google Chrome.

But the same chart just don't plot the data in firefox.

I have already tried to update both browsers but even though, I still getting this problem.

Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmfZ1.jpg

Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRjQs.jpg

it is possible to see by the chart in Firefox that I'm getting the data (check the number in the axis). The issue is about ploting the data.

Here is the code of the chart.

```
class EstadoFrotaGraficoController {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'estadoFrotaGrafico';
    }

$onInit() {
    this.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'stackedAreaChart',
            height: 450,
            margin : {
                top: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 30,
                left: 40
            },
            x: function(d){return d[0];},
            y: function(d){return d[1];},
            useVoronoi: false,
            clipEdge: true,
            duration: 100,
            useInteractiveGuideline: true,
            xAxis: {
                showMaxMin: false,
                tickFormat: function(d) {
                    return d3.time.format('%b %d')(new Date(d));
                },
                rotateLabels:(-15), 
                tickValues: function (d) {  //set axis everyday frequency
                  return d[0].values.map(function (item) {
                      return item.x;
                  })
                },
            },
            yAxis: {
                tickFormat: function(d){
                    return d3.format(',.2f')(d);
                }
            },
            zoom: {
                enabled: true,
                scaleExtent: [1, 10],
                useFixedDomain: false,
                useNiceScale: false,
                horizontalOff: false,
                verticalOff: true,
                unzoomEventType: 'dblclick.zoom'
            },
            controlOptions: ['Stacked', 'Expanded'],
            controlLabels: {
                stacked: 'Empilhado',
                expanded: 'Expandido'
            }
        }
    };
}

$onChanges() {
    if (this.fleet) {
        this.data = this._generateData(this.fleet);
        console.log(this.data);
    }
}

_generateData(fleet) {
    let formattedFleet = [];

    formattedFleet.push(this._generateChartValues("Menor que 20mm", '#c88180', fleet, 'group1'));
    formattedFleet.push(this._generateChartValues("Entre 20mm e 30mm", '#008f83', fleet, 'group2'));
    formattedFleet.push(this._generateChartValues("Entre 30mm e 40 mm", '#e47c26', fleet, 'group3'));
    formattedFleet.push(this._generateChartValues("Maior que 40mm", '#3b74bb', fleet, 'group4'));

    return formattedFleet;
}

_generateChartValues(chartName, chartColor, originalData, seriesName) {
    return {
        key: chartName,
        color: chartColor,
        values: originalData.map(function(record) {
            return [new Date(record.date), record[seriesName]]
        })
    }
}

}

export default EstadoFrotaGraficoController;
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Console errors?

Comment: Nothing in Chrome. This in Firefox: https://imgur.com/a/HlDoI. It means "processing error in the value of 'clip-path'. Ignored statement"

Comment: That's not pure D3. What else are you using to create the chart? Please add all the relevant tags.

Comment: It's true, thanks about the comment. I'm using nvd3.js

Comment: Can you log the clip path value to see what it's got a problem with?